# What is the point of this metaphor?

Tags: meaning, metaphors

It was a little death, not being able to make a tale out of the small moments of life.

I don't see the connection between death and life. How do these relate and make this metaphor effective?

Comment: Context please. What's the story beforehand? Can you give the full paragraph?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because even if context were to be provided this seems like a LitCrit question.

Comment: @Jim, disagree.  This is not about a particular work, it's usage?

Comment: @dwoz- The question is "what is the point of this metaphor?" I read that to mean, "why did the author choose to employ this metaphor.  Or perhaps it's asking, "why does this metaphor exist in the first place" which again, calls for us to answer the question, "why did the original author decide that they needed a metaphor to convey a particular concept?"

Comment: I would probably, absent further context, take it to mean a meaningless life or a meaningless death, but that's only a guess.  Much more context is needed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because more context is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is from *[The Secret River](https://books.google.com/books?id=s8Pt0ZG4-eQC&pg=PA209&lpg=PA209&dq=It%20was%20a%20little%20death,%20not%20being%20able%20to%20make%20a%20tale%20out%20of%20the%20small%20moments%20of%20life&source=bl&ots=_oZN3DDAn9&sig=aZhi4DXV5_ajg_zBe5TVhv-J130&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAGoVChMIgZSuwYmbyQIVw3gmCh2fhw2p#v=onepage&q=It%20was%20a%20little%20death%2C%20not%20being%20able%20to%20make%20a%20tale%20out%20of%20the%20small%20moments%20of%20life&f=false)* by Kate Grenville.  The protagonist is an Englishman, William Thornhill. Condemned to death for thievery, in 1806 his sentence is commuted to exile in New South Wales, Australia.  His family, including his wife Sal, accompanies him.  Here is the context:

> Sal told Smasher everything:  Swan Lane and Butler's Buildings, how
>   Dick had considerately waited until they put into into Cape Town to be born,
>   why the inn in Sydney had been called the Sign of the Pickle Herring. 
>   She showed him the trunk of the tree he was sitting under, with the
>   tally-marks, and made the day's mark then and there to show him how
>   she did it, although it was only afternoon.
>
> Thronhill saw for the first time how much she missed having people
>   around her.   **It was a little death, not being able to make a tale
>   out of the small moments of life** and share them with someone for
>   whom they were new.  Thornhill surprised a pang, hearing her voice
>   warm, and watching how her face came to life as it had not since they
>   had been on the river.

Thornhill realizes in hearing his wife narrate her life that although he has escaped a literal death sentence in England, this has condemned his wife to a profound isolation so numbing that he calls it a "little death."  It's not quite the end of life, but it's not a full life either, for that would require being able to share one's existence, including the quotidian, with other people.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that some context would be helpful. If I were to hazard a guess, I would think that the author of that sentence is attempting to state something such as, "I suffered greatly (a little death) by my inability to craft a story from the incidents that define life."

Answer (score 0):

I read this a little differently than my co-respondents.  I see "a little death" in this snippet as describing "a meaningless death."

The pedestrian plodder, ruminating in and about his mundane day, never performing any more than the mundane stupid tasks of survival that bring the next day, does not rise to any level that results in a heroic or noteworthy death.  The passing of this human dust-mote off the mortal coil is no more noticeable than his occupation of it.